# Value of $g'(\frac{1}{2})$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Given than for each $a\in (0,1)$

$$\lim_{h \to 0^+} \int_{h}^{1-h} t^{-a} (1-t)^{a-1} dt$$

exists. Let this limit be $g(a)$. In addition it is given that the function $g(a)$ is differentiable on $(0,1)$

Then the value of $g'(\frac{1}{2})$ is ?

How should I go about? Need hints

Comment: Is the answer $0$

Comment: @ArchisWelankar Correct

Comment: Maybe you meant the integrand to be $t^{-a} (1-t)^{a-1}$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael The question is correctly written

Answer (score 4):

$$g(a) = \rm{B}(1-a, 2-a) = {\frac {\Gamma \left( 1-a \right) \Gamma \left( 2-a \right) }{\Gamma
 \left( 3-2\,a \right) }}$$
where $\rm{B}$ is the [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).  Then

$$ g'(a) = -{\frac {\Psi \left( 1-a \right) \Gamma \left( 1-a \right) \Gamma
 \left( 2-a \right) }{\Gamma \left( 3-2\,a \right) }}-{\frac {\Gamma
 \left( 1-a \right) \Psi \left( 2-a \right) \Gamma \left( 2-a \right) 
}{\Gamma \left( 3-2\,a \right) }}+2\,{\frac {\Gamma \left( 1-a
 \right) \Gamma \left( 2-a \right) \Psi \left( 3-2\,a \right) }{\Gamma
 \left( 3-2\,a \right) }}
$$
and
$$ \eqalign{g'(1/2) &= \frac{\left( \gamma+2\,\ln  \left( 2 \right)  \right) \pi}{2}+\frac{\pi\,
 \left(- 2+\gamma+2\,\ln  \left( 2 \right)  \right)}{2} +\pi\, \left( 1-
\gamma \right) \cr &= 2 \pi \ln(2)}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $g(a)=g(1-a)$, we can say that $g'(a)=-g'(1-a)$. Putting $a=\frac{1}{2}$, we get $g'(\frac{1}{2}) = -g'(\frac{1}{2})$. This implies $g'(\frac{1}{2})=0$

EDIT: $$g(a)= \lim_{h \to 0} \int_{h}^{1-h} t^{-a} (1-t)^{a-1} dt$$
$$g(1-a)=\lim_{h \to 0} \int_{h}^{1-h} t^{a-1} (1-t)^{-a} dt$$

Using $\int_{a}^{b}f(x) dx=\int_{a}^{b}f(a+b-x) dx$

$$g(1-a)=\lim_{h \to 0} \int_{h}^{1-h} (1-t)^{a-1} t^{-a} dt$$

This proves $g(a)=g(1-a).$

Comment: As you can $g(a) \neq g(1-a)$ so your calculation is wrong.

Comment: Perhaps your question should have $t^{a} $ instead of $t^{-a} $ to make your solution correct.